# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number while calling stored function

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5

I try to call to a stored function in a package that returns a number:

```
function LOGIN(USERNAME in varchar2 default null
               , PASSWORD in varchar2 default null) 
         return number;
```

It returns 0 or negative integer for failure and a positive integer for success.
Here is my PHP code calling the function:

```
$sql = ":v_res := PACK.LOGIN(:p_user, :p_pass)";
$bindings = [ ':p_user' => 'test', ':p_pass' => '1234', ':v_res' => & $result];

$statement oci_parse($connection, $sql);
foreach ($bindings as $k => & $v) {
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, $k, $v, customSizeOf($v), determineSqlType($v));
}

oci_execute($statement);
```

When I use result as shown (not defined before using in binding) it returns "Undefined variable" warning. If I suppress the warning and move on, it is bound with null, size of -1 and type 1 (SQLT_CHR); If I define result like `$result = -1;`, it is bound with -1, size of PHP_INT_SIZE and type 3 (SQLT_INT).

Either way, on execute, this error is produced

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work as you have to wrap your call either in a PL/SQL block or in a SQL query:

```
$sql = "BEGIN :v_res := PACK.LOGIN(:p_user, :p_pass); END";
```

Or

```
$sql = "SELECT caller(:p_user, :p_pass) v_res FROM DUAL"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked, I already don't know why, but it works:

```
$result = -1;

$sql = <<<"SQL"
begin
    :V_RETURN := PACK.LOGIN(
        USERNAME => :USERNAME,
        PASSWORD => :PASSWORD
    );
end;
SQL;

$bindings = [
    ':USERNAME' => $username,
    ':PASSWORD' => $password,
    ':V_RETURN' => & $result,
];

$statement oci_parse($connection, $sql);
foreach ($bindings as $k => & $v) {
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, $k, $v, customSizeOf($v), determineSqlType($v));
}

oci_execute($statement);
```

It should have been passed to the array by reference, but still no idea why it works and the other one threw binding error; if anything, it should bind a memory and it would not be `$result`.

**Update:** It's better to use `SQLT_LNG` type instead of `SQLT_INT` since it may not work properly on Unix systems and give `int(-4294967295)` for everything (overflow). Contrary to public belief, Windows is fine for both `SQLT_INT` and `SQLT_LNG` so I suggest for compatibility issues use `SQLT_LNG`.

Answer (score -1):

@Cunning : Please try the below options.

1. Check http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php .
2. Try changing your binding order

   $bindings = [':v_res' => & $result, ':p_user' => 'test', ':p_pass' => '1234'];

Comment: Binding doesn't work like that. That is the beauty of proper binding with oci8. It doesn't depend on order; it is sensitive to data length in byte though.